# Historical data appears seasonal, but forecasts from auto.arima are linear

Tags: forecasting, arima, seasonality

I am surprised how often the `auto.arima` function from the "forecast" package in R returns straight linear forecasts when there appears to be fairly strong seasonality in the historic data.

I've attached an example:

```
    tpits=ts(TPI,start=c(1986,1),end=c(2020,1),frequency=1)
    fit=auto.arima(tpits)
```

The data is annual and varies significantly but the forecast is completely linear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CV is not the most appropriate form for code checking, can you be more specific on your issue, to inform other readers better?

Comment: why don't you post the data in an excel format and I will try and answer your question

Comment: You say data is annual, then how can it have strong seasonality?

Comment: @forecaster which is in part why I wanted to see the data.

Comment: swenham, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the time series to have `frequency=1`, you are explicitly ruling out seasonal patterns in them, and also ruling out seasonal models in `auto.arima`. That is, SARIMA models will not be considered during the model selection process in `auto.arima`.

If you have seasonal data, you should specify the number of periods in a full seasonal cycle, e.g. `frequency=12` for monthly data. When supplied to `auto.arima`, such a series would allow for SARIMA models to be considered and hence for forecasts reflecting seasonality.

(In principle, even yearly data could be seasonal if there were something special about every odd year but not even year. Then you could try specifying `frequency=2`.This is just an example.)